# Why don't i have an option called collection?

Tags: particles

I am a beginner to Blender, and I am watching a tutorial on how to make a donut. This guy has an option called "collection" which he has and I don't. Can someone please explain why?

It happens at 17:25 in [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZ5ungDgFNc)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Either you have not changed the *Particle Emitter* to use collections, or you have not created a collection for the sprinkles. BlenderGuru changed the particle emitter to use collections earlier in the video [here](https://youtu.be/aZ5ungDgFNc?t=575).

If you did not create a new collection, you right-click in that window in the top right corner, and press *New.* This will create a new collection that you can rename by double-clicking, or pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can select all the objects you want to move to the new collection (in this case, all your sprinkles), press <kbd>M</kbd> and select *+ New Collection*. BlenderGuru showed this process in the previous video [here](https://youtu.be/jNmnPXY9UQA?t=60).

[image: Collection]

**Edit: unrelated to original question, related to comments**

Looking at the objects list in the top right corner, The donut and the sphere both have *Particle Emitters* applied.

[image]

To remove them, first, select the object (either the donut or the sphere, you don't want to delete the particle emitter from the icing), then go to the *Particle Properties* tab (blue icon with a couple of dots connected with lines). Then, press the minus button shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). I just love how you give detailed and researched answers to even the most basic questions. Thank you for making this site a better place :).

Comment: I went through the donut tutorial too :) I know the feeling of being completely lost all too well, so helping others get past the learning curve is the least I can do to contribute back to the community.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me I very much apriceate it

Comment: And by the way, can you check my file for errors, of course, you don't have to I just have a fear of messing up

Comment: It looked fine to me when I looked at it. If something else goes wrong and you can't find a solution, just post another question.

Comment: This is the link                             [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=550dGEZ9" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/550dGEZ9/)

Comment: Alright looked over it a bit. I can see that you accidentally applied the Particle Emitter to the wrong objects a couple of times, no worries there, just be sure that you remove the ones on the wrong objects just to keep things neat. There are things that you could do to improve the realism, but that comes over time with practice. You're doing great for your first project!

Comment: how would i do that

Comment: Updated the answer